# Excel VAR.P calculates slightly different number

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a little question. I'm calculating variance for a population. My data set is as follows:

```
667070000
660330000
665770000
682335000
698355000
715185000
735400000
754550000
774510000
796025000
818315000
841105000
862030000
881940000
900350000
916395000
930685000
943455000
956165000
969005000
981235000
993885000
1008630000
1023310000
1036825000
```

My calculation is **15,254,390,242,640,000** and it's the correct one. However, Excel **VAR.P** function returns **15,254,390,242,639,700**. The numbers are different (very little difference, but still different). Why this happens?

Comment: What Formula you have tried so far, since I'm getting different result!

Comment: You achieve the accuracy level of double datatype. So the last, 15th, digit is not accurate.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. @RajeshS I used VAR.P

Comment: @Akina why VAR.P doesnt use the same DOUBLE mechanism? It's a standard formula!